# Why does firefox white out pages in codepen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

### Background:

I'm creating my navigation bar for my portfolio in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ixfKC)

I've notice that everything works excellently in chrome; however, when testing the pen in firefox, after click of a li item of a navigation.  The page errors out by filling the screen with white.  I noticed a similar problem with this in other pens.

Reference Example:
[return false example from a previous stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847585/firefox-makes-simple-jquery-slidetoggle-disappear)

The remedy was in the js `return false` had to be present.

---

### Question:

This example is different because I'm not using any javascript.  Only html and css.
**Why does firefox have this consistent problem in codepen?  What do I need to know to understand why this problem occurs so that in future coding I can be knowledgeable of this firefox caveat entirely?  Lastly, why doesn't this happen in chrome?**

[codepen example](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ixfKC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking out your codepen, it's clear it's nothing to do with your code.

I've done a search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619094/firefox-reloading-parent-page-in-iframe-when-clicking-named-anchor) which seems like a very bug to the one you've come across. Looks like there's already a [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598) ticket open for this issue, but as of yet it's unresolved.